Is my proof for differentiability from the derivative definition correct?
Context:
I'm working on a problem in real analysis to show that if a function $f(x)$ has a derivative at $x = x_0$, then $f(x)$ is differentiable at $x_0$.
I used the following reasoning, and I'd like to know if my proof is correct or if there are any gaps. Additionally, I’ve included a proof from a textbook for comparison.

My Proof:
Assume $f(x)$ has a derivative at $x = x_0$, that is:
$$ 
\lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{f(x_0 + \Delta x) - f(x_0)}{\Delta x} = A
$$
Let $\Delta y = f(x_0 + \Delta x) - f(x_0)$. Substituting this, we can rewrite the limit as:
$$ 
\lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x} = A
$$
Rearranging gives:
$$ 
\lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{\Delta y - A\Delta x}{\Delta x} = 0
$$
This means:
$$ 
\Delta y - A\Delta x = o(\Delta x) \quad (\Delta x \to 0)
$$
This establishes differentiability.

Book's Proof:
Assume $f(x)$ has a derivative at $x = x_0$, that is:
$$ 
\lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{f(x_0 + \Delta x) - f(x_0)}{\Delta x} = A
$$
Let $\Delta y = f(x_0 + \Delta x) - f(x_0)$. Substituting this, we can rewrite the limit as:
$$ 
\lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x} = A
$$
Thus, we can express $\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$ as:
$$ 
\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x} = A + \alpha(\Delta x) \quad (\Delta x \neq 0)
$$
where $\alpha(\Delta x) \to 0$ as $\Delta x \to 0$. Rewriting for $\Delta y$, we have:
$$ 
\Delta y = A\Delta x + \alpha(\Delta x)\cdot\Delta x
$$
Where $\alpha(\Delta x)$ satisfies the conditions,
$$ 
\lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \alpha(\Delta x) = 0, \alpha(0) = 0
$$
Since $\alpha(\Delta x)\cdot\Delta x = o(\Delta x)$ as $\Delta x \to 0$, we can rewrite:
$$ 
\Delta y = A\Delta x + o(\Delta x) \quad (\Delta x \to 0)
$$
This establishes differentiability.

Question:
Is the rearrangement valid in my proof? Does it rigorously establish differentiability, or am I missing any steps or considerations?

Additional Notes:
In the book I am currently reading, the concepts of "having a derivative" and "being differentiable" at a point are defined differently, although they are eventually shown to be equivalent. Specifically:

Having a derivative at $x = x_0$ is defined as:
$$
  \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{f(x_0 + \Delta x) - f(x_0)}{\Delta x} = A
  $$

Being differentiable at $x = x_0$ is defined as:
$$
  \Delta y = A\Delta x + o(\Delta x) \quad (\Delta x \to 0)
  $$
where $\Delta y = f(x_0 + \Delta x) - f(x_0)$ and $A$ is a constant independent of $\Delta x$.


Although these definitions are equivalent after being proved, the distinction is emphasized in the text. My proof focuses on showing this equivalence and verifying the rigor of the steps involved.

The [tag:solution-verification] tag info states that “‘Is this proof correct?’ is too broad or missing context. Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so.”

What is the difference between “having a derivative” and “being differentiable” at a point?

Your proof is same as your text book's proof. The book is trying to justify the $o(\Delta x) $ with a bit more steps. For me the two answers should get same credit.
